# jQuery and css two step sign-up from

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am about to create a two-step sign-up form.
I have JavaScript validation.
But it works on end of step two.

What I did?
I basically create a submit form, divide into two pieces with divs.

```
   <div id="signup">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>First Name<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Last Name<span class="req">*</span>

                    </label>
                    <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Email Address<span class="req">*</span>

                </label>
                <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>

                </label>
                <input type="password" required autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#step2">Step 2</a>

            </li>
    </div>

    <div id="step2" style="display: none;">
        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Favorite Book:<span class="req">*</span>

            </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Interests:<span class="req">*</span>

            </label>
            <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Get Started</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My aim is checking step one, and if everything is okay letting user fulfill the form on step two.

In my case, you can just skip the Step one. And you will see warning later on Step two. Very late.

Here you can live demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/18cpd3Lw/4/

I want to check steps partly but submit once.

Comment: What is the problem? I don't understand...

Comment: @somethinghere It's there end of the HTML section. I couldn't make it work in JavaScript section.

Comment: You have to wrap it in jQuery-ready: https://jsfiddle.net/18cpd3Lw/4/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if you try to fulfill the form incorrectly, let's say you didn't put correct e-mail, it gives you error at step 2. but e-mail part is on step one. and i am trying to get this error there on step one, earlier.

Comment: You need to remove the required attribute when you stay at step 2, or otherwise you need to validate the first form before change to step 2.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, my aim is validate the first form before change to step 2. but I couln't make it as long as I want to send them as one form. I need to do something on "Step 2" button but this is where I stuck

Comment: You must to store in variables the form1 data after validate, then validate form2 and retrieve stored data + form2 data and it it's ready to submit (ajax for example)

Comment: Are you performing validation in JS or in backend?

Comment: @GobSmack, I validate like that: `<input type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>`

Comment: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples might help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. You already divide *one* `form` into *two*. You are about to `post` them *at once*. All you need to do is checking first tab before jump into the second one.

Please try;

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Multiple step form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #personal_information,
        #company_information{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" id="myform">

                <fieldset id="account_information" class="">
                    <legend>Account information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="conf_password" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Confirm password</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="conf_password" name="conf_password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">next</a></p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="company_information" class="">
                    <legend>Account information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="company" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Company</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Company">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="url" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Website url</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="Website url">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary next">next</a></p>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="personal_information" class="">
                    <legend>Personal information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-primary" id="previous" >Previous</a></p>
                    <p><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit"></p>
                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Custom method to validate username
            $.validator.addMethod("usernameRegex", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/i.test(value);
            }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers");

            $(".next").click(function(){
                var form = $("#myform");
                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'span',
                    errorClass: 'help-block',
                    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass("has-error");
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-error");
                    },
                    rules: {
                        username: {
                            required: true,
                            usernameRegex: true,
                            minlength: 6,
                        },
                        password : {
                            required: true,
                        },
                        conf_password : {
                            required: true,
                            equalTo: '#password',
                        },
                        company:{
                            required: true,
                        },
                        url:{
                            required: true,
                        },
                        name: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 3,
                        },

                    },
                    messages: {
                        username: {
                            required: "Username required",
                        },
                        password : {
                            required: "Password required",
                        },
                        conf_password : {
                            required: "Password required",
                            equalTo: "Password don't match",
                        },
                        name: {
                            required: "Name required",
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: "Email required",
                        },
                    }
                });
                if (form.valid() === true){
                    if ($('#account_information').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#account_information');
                        next_fs = $('#company_information');
                    }else if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                        current_fs = $('#company_information');
                        next_fs = $('#personal_information');
                    }

                    next_fs.show(); 
                    current_fs.hide();
                }
            });

            $('#previous').click(function(){
                if($('#company_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#company_information');
                    next_fs = $('#account_information');
                }else if ($('#personal_information').is(":visible")){
                    current_fs = $('#personal_information');
                    next_fs = $('#company_information');
                }
                next_fs.show(); 
                current_fs.hide();
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```